# How to remove version tag in Cloudinary Url?

Tags: java, android, cloudinary

I download my image to Cloudinary using:

```
String requestId = MediaManager.get().upload(bytes).dispatch();
```

And result is :
https://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/v1534590507/18082018020824374.jpg

But I want https://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/18082018020824374.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you're referring to (v1....) is the version number and cannot be removed when uploading a new image. Please note that we use versions as a mean to ensure that the most recent image is used.

Cloudinary's does not require the version component to be present in URLs (but you might get a previously cached version in this case).

For more information please refer to the following- https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520912-What-are-image-versions-